# Angular UI-Calendar not working with click events

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, angular-ui

Trying to use this Angular Calendar http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar but it is not working.

The problem is click events, I'm not able to work any of them.

This is the code I use: 
(Using curly brackets, because if removed anything worked)

```
<div ui-calendar="{{uiConfig.calendar}}" ng-model="eventSources"></div>
$scope.uiConfig = {
        calendar:{
            lang: 'es',
            height: '100%',
            editable: true,
            header:{
                left: 'title',
                center: '',
                right: 'today prev,next'
            },
            eventClick: $scope.alertOnEventClick,
            eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
            eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
            eventRender: $scope.eventRender,
            loading: $scope.loading
        }
    };
```

Every thing beside of this is working well.

Debbuging the code I realize those functions are not passing to directive.

```
function getOptions(){
      var calendarSettings = attrs.uiCalendar ? scope.$eval(attrs.uiCalendar) : {},
          fullCalendarConfig;

      fullCalendarConfig = controller.getFullCalendarConfig(calendarSettings, uiCalendarConfig);
```

[image: PrintScreen debbugin angular calendar]
BTW: I'm using this angular version.

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found, in the script file published in online demo, a difference when reading settings, this line:

```
Line 229.
var calendarSettings = attrs.uiCalendar ? scope.$eval(attrs.uiCalendar) : {}
```

The online version has a **$parent** call, so I just update the file and works fine.

```
var calendarSettings = attrs.uiCalendar ? scope.$parent.$eval(attrs.uiCalendar) : {}
```